# Generating HTML (i.e. br and p tags) from plaintext in C++

Tags: c++, html, regex, string

I've got a bunch of text like this:

```
foo
bar

baz
```

What's likely to be the most efficient way in C++ of transforming that to this:

```
<p>foo<br />bar</p>
<p>baz</p>
```

for large(ish) quantities of text (up to 8000 characters).

I'm happy to use boost's `regex_replace`, but I was wondering if string searching for `\n\n` might be more efficient? Any thoughts? Any other approaches?

Most third-party libraries are not available to me in the environment I'm working in.

Comment: Uh ... What's with the empty <br> element?

Comment: @unwind - the `<br />` as opposed to `<br>`? `<br>` would be invalid XHTML.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the triple newlines - I updated my answer.

Comment: Make a awk or perl script for that purpose.

Comment: I don’t believe any of these suggestions (as of 2011-02-15) take into account whitespace. Lines that begin with a number of spaces or tabs in the input, or that have words with     a big gap between them will be ignored, assuming your HTML is displayed with typical `white-space` interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a simple state-machine. It does require 
comparison of the state for each time through the loop, but 
it should not matter (it could be optimised by having a sub 
loop in the third state - see below). The start state would 
be the same as when two newlines have be encountered. There 
would be a variable for the previous character and one for 
keeping track of the position of the last newline (used for
generating output).

The states would be:

- encountered double new line. Action when enter into state: output of <p>, the line and </p>
- encountered single new line. Action when enter into state: output of the line and
- encountered normal character

The program would look more like a C-program, though...

Comment: +1 - Got a simple version of this working (though I've adapted it slightly - start by pushing <p>, and the start state is "no newlines encountered". On encountering a newline I set "newline encountered", unless it was already set, at which point I unset it, and push </p><p>. If I encounter a non-newline character x, I push <br />x, and unset "newline encountered". However, I think Vinay's answer might be a bit quicker and easier to manage.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to encode your text for HTML entities! e.g. if you have

```
foo&
```

you'll need to translate it appropriately:

```
foo&amp;
```

(don't know if you're aware - it's just not been mentioned and often gets forgotten!)

Answer (score 1):

If your data contains no surprises, you can just replace all instances of `\n\n` with `</p><p>`, followed by replacing all `\n` with `<br/>`. Then bracket the result with `<p>` and `</p>`, and you're done. This doesn't deal with edge cases (for example, three newlines separating paragraphs) but it is pretty simple, and quicker than writing a state machine!

**Update:** Obviously, if you have `\n\n\n`, `\n\n\n\n` etc. then you can also replace those with `</p><p>` starting with the longer sequences first.

Comment: +1 - That looks like it'll work well and be very quick - thanks. For some reason that (now obvious-seeming) solution hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: Sadly, a lot of my input has three newlines separating paragraphs. D'oh!

Comment: I wonder if a `regex_replace` might be more appropriate to replace longer sequences of `\n\n...` with `</p><p>`.

Answer (score 0):

Tight, fast, and ugly state machine.  Handles degenerate cases, like empty input, blank lines at the beginning of the input, long strings of blank lines between paragraphs, and a missing newline marker at the end of the input.

```
template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
void TextToHTML(InputIt begin, InputIt end, OutputIt target) {
start:  if (begin == end) return;
        if (*begin == '\n') { ++begin; goto start; }
        *target++ = '<'; *target++ = 'p'; *target++ = '>';
para:   *target++ = *begin++;
        if (begin == end) goto endp;
        if (*begin != '\n') goto para;
        if (++begin == end) goto endp;
        if (*begin == '\n') goto endp;
        *target++ = '<'; *target++ = 'b'; *target++ = 'r'; *target++ = ' '; *target++ = '/'; *target++ = '>';
        goto para;
endp:   *target++ = '<'; *target++ = '/'; *target++ = 'p'; *target++ = '>'; *target++ = '\n';
        goto start;
}

int main() {
    std::string text = "foo\nbar\n\nbaz";
    std::string html;
    TextToHTML(text.begin(), text.end(), std::back_inserter(html));
    std::cout << html << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```